# Construct2 - Layout transition is not showing animations

Tags: animation, construct-2

I am having a problem with my game: when I press the "go back to main menu" button at the pause menu, I go back to the main menu layout. The problem is: It does not run sprites' animations of the main menu, just movements. How can I fix it? Oh, and by the way, reset layout did not work. I tried debugging it and found out that the sprite animation is playing, but the current frame is not changing. PLease help me

Answer (score 0):

Without taking a look at your spritesheet, I'd do the following to try to find the bug:

1-See if animation speed is set to 0 or if it's being set to 0 somewhere in your events.

2-See the time scale. I, personally, use time scale = 0 to make pauses. I think you can bug your animations if you do not set it properly again to 1.0 but so far I don't think this has happened to me yet so I'm not sure.

3-See if your animation is set to loop. Perhaps C2 is considering that your animation has already ended its first run.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. Turned out I was pausing and setting the time scale to 0 and then returning to the title screen, only after reading this did I realize I needed to change the timescale bqck to 1.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a very good answer for the question in hand. If you are going to post an answer, please make it specific and detailed so that future users can benefit from it.